# Como passar multiplos arrays para página em PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

→ `$scope.items = [];`

→ `dados = $('#meu_form').serialize();`

Gostaria de saber: como enviar/receber/ler os arrays acima para uma página em PHP?

JavaScript:

```
    app = angular.module("app",[]);
    app.controller("controlador", ["$scope", "$http",

    function($scope, $http){
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        var dados = $('#meu_form').serialize();

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'pagina.php',
          data    :
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })

    };
```

pagina.php

```
$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

foreach ($dados as $key => &$value) {
    $codigo     = $value['codigo'];
    $quantidade = (float)$value['quantidade'];
    $v_total    = $value['v_total'];

}

$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Dentro de `$http` em `data    :` tente colocar `data    : {scope: $scope.items, dados: dados }`, e no PHP `$_POST['scope'] ` e  `$_POST['dados'] ` para recuperar respectivamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @ivcs, mas não deu certo. Posso te convidar pro chat?

Comment: Estranho, aqui funcionou, retorna algum erro no console? Tentei com os arrays: `var lista1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']; var lista2 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];` e no data com `{ lista1: lista1, lista2: lista2 }`, no PHP só percorri o `$_POST` e concatenei as chaves em uma string, o resultado foi o esperado.

Comment: -- Pode sim :)))

Comment: So um instante, @ivcs.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51217/como-passar-multiplos-arrays-para-pagina-em-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **JS**, você simplesmente monta um outro *array* com esses *arrays*, no campo de `data` do `$http`, assim:

```
app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("controlador", ["$scope", "$http",

function($scope, $http){
$scope.items = [];

$scope.submitForm = function() {
    var dados = $('#meu_form').serialize();

    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'pagina.php',
      data    : {scope: $scope.items, dados: dados}
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })

};
```

E no **PHP**, você pode pegar os valores assim:

```
<?php 

// transforma o JSON enviado em array associativo
$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 

$p = $dados['dados']; // pega o formulário serializado do AJAX 
parse_str($p, $dados['dados']); // tranforma em array de PHP 

?>
```

Dessa maneira, segue a legenda de identificação das variáveis:

- `$dados['scope']` - seria igual ao `$scope.items`.
- `$dados['dados']` - seria igual ao `$('#meu_form').serialize()`, já em array.

Para acessar um campo do formulário, como por exemplo o *input* `email`, você vai usar:

```
$dados['dados']['email']
```

Já para acessar um campo de `email` de um elemento no *scope*, será:

```
$dados['scope'][0]['email']
```

Caso queira percorrer todos elementos do seu *scope*, será:

```
foreach($dados['scope'] as $item) {
    echo '<br>Nome: '  .  $item['nome'];
    echo '<br>Email: ' .  $item['email'];
}
```

Logo, `$item['email']` seria igual `$dados['scope'][X]['email']`, onde *X* é o elemento percorrido atualmente pelo `foreach`.